# Ubuntu is okay - Old Vista is still not loading after boot-repair

Tags: grub2, windows-vista

I have cleaned an old ubuntu - that caused my Grub loader to go crap. I have managed to put a new ubuntu instead of that - but my Vista is stil unaccessible.
I have made boot-repair to run (but maybe my settings did not worked).
I have checked later the MBR record correction too. 
Can anybody chat with me or can I share my screen?

Csaba

Answer (score 1):

In Vista, the procedure to fix the master boot record is a bit different. You have to start up Vista in the Recovery Environment and then run the bootrec command. Here’s how.

1. First, load up the Windows Vista disc in your drive and press any key to boot from the disc.
2. Choose the language, time, currency, etc and click Next. Now click on Repair Your Computer.

[image]

3- Choose the operating system to repair and click Next. When the System Recovery Options dialog comes up, choose the Command Prompt.

[image]

4- Now type bootrec.exe and press Enter. This will rebuild the boot configuration data and hopefully fix your problem. You can also run the command with switches to fix just the master boot record (/fixmbr), the boot sector (/fixboot), or rebuild the entire BCD (/rebuildbcd).

Comment: thanks Maythux! I am on the way to go home, and try it with my recovery cd.